# What happened in autoincrement function in Perl?

Tags: perl

I've got a question in Perl studying.

```
$a = "Z9"; print ++$a;
```

It prints out `AA0`. This can easily understood that 9 increased by 1 gets 10 and Z increased 1 gets AA. Just like 99+1.
But what happened if I flipped over Z and 9:

```
$a = "9Z"; print ++$a;
```

This will get `10`. Why the letter Z is gone? Where did it gone?

Regards,
Neil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"9Z"` is interpreted like a number, and therefore the non-numeric ending gets truncated before the autoincrement.  The same would be true of `"9 the rest of this string is ignored"`.

This is similar to the way that `print "2foo" + "2bar";` will output `4`.

The string magic that you observe with `"Z9"` is documented in [perlop #Auto-increment and Auto-decrement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)

> The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it. If you increment a variable that is numeric, or that has ever been used in a numeric context, you get a normal increment. If, however, the variable has been used in only string contexts since it was set, and has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/` , the increment is done as a string, preserving each character within its range, with carry:
>
> 1. `print ++($foo = "99"); # prints "100"`
> 2. `print ++($foo = "a0"); # prints "a1"`
> 3. `print ++($foo = "Az"); # prints "Ba"`
> 4. `print ++($foo = "zz"); # prints "aaa"`

Comment: You are right, Miller. I found any alphabetic which followed by a numeric will be truncated, no matter how long, no matter which one. Any increment or decrement operation of num+alph will only produce the numeric part and truncate the alphabetic part. Maybe this is one of a mechanism of Perl.

Comment: @NeilWang, as documented, the magic auto-increment pattern matches only 0-or-more letters followed by 0-or-more digits.  Anything else (e.g. digits followed by letters) does not match the pattern, so you get a normal numeric increment.